# Inset shelf construction for a network rack

Tags: construction, architecture

I want to construct a hole in the wall type shelf.  On the other side of the wall is an attic space for the side of the house, it has plenty of room to do what I need.

I will be making the frame, and adding dry-wall to the sides and top, but then tile the bottom of it (i think).  Basically a shelf inset, but it is going to be a bit deeper than the average shelf, and taller.  I am putting a Network rack inside of it, I have the ventilation and electrical figured out.

What I want to know is, how can I ensure the bottom of the shelf is reinforced enough to withstand a heavy weight?  I suspect possibly 200 lbs max.

Comment: http://www.woodbin.com/calcs/sagulator/

Comment: Have you figured out power and A/C?

Comment: Yes, AC and Power is figured out.